# The type initializer for 'Sap.Data.Hana.HanaConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find libADONETHDB.dll

Tags: c#, dll, ado.net, cpu-architecture, hana

I have a problem only on a specific machine.
I have two programs with a reference to **Sap.Data.Hana.v4.5.dll**, the ADO.NET Provider for .NET 4.5 for HANA database.
When my programs instantiates a connection object with

```
dbConnection = new HanaConnection(...);
```

I get this error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sap.Data.Hana.HanaConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find libADONETHDB.dll.
   at Sap.Data.Hana.HanaUnmanagedDll.SearchNativeDlls(String regKeyName)
   at Sap.Data.Hana.HanaUnmanagedDll..ctor()
   at Sap.Data.Hana.HanaUnmanagedDll.get_Instance()
   at Sap.Data.Hana.HanaConnection..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at [...my program calls...]
```

**Why can't it find libADONETHDB.dll?**

My applications are build one in 32-bit, the other in 64-bit.
On this machine I installed SAP HANA client 2.8.20.23662 (latest version) both 32-bit and 64-bit.
The file that cannot be found seems to exist:

[image: libADONETHDB.dll search results]

Comment: May be a dll that is required by libADONETHDB.dll is missing this could lead to this exception. May be the dependency walker helps to analyse this.

Comment: @DanielW. I tried to use Dependency walker, but I could not find anything... Could you please address me on how to use it? Should I open libADONETHDB.dll in DW and check something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hipotesis is that GAC had been corrupted with version 1 of Sap.Data.Hana.v4.5.dll:

[image: GAC]

Probably in the past HANA Client version 1 had been installed and removed and uninstallation hadn't cleaned the GAC.
My program uses HANA Client of any version, works both with version 1 and 2. For some reason when they start they seem to take version 1 of Sap.Data.Hana.v4.5.dll in the GAC. Process Monitor (thanks [@sc911](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67536293/505893)) confirms it:

[image: ProcMon]

This .NET DLL then looks for some unmanaged DLLs in C:\Program Files (x86)\hdbclient. Version 1 seems to look for libADONETHDB.dll in root folder.
But currently in this machine in that folder we have HANA Client 2.x and its folder structure is quite different from that of version 1 (there is no libADONETHDB.dll in root folder).
Hence the error in this question.
All this is valid both for 32-bit and 64-bit HANA Client.

**I solved renaming or deleting version 1 folder in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Sap.Data.Hana.v4.5** (probably there are better ways for performing this cleanup).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) while running the relevant part of the program to see, which file is missing and the path it should be in. Exclude all other events than file events and filter out all SUCCESS messages.

Perhaps it is referenced relative to the calling DLL (where `Sap.Data.Hana.HanaUnmanagedDll.SearchNativeDlls` is defined).

Comment: Thank you! Process Monitor gave me a lot of information on which libraries were loaded and led me to the cause of the problem!